# Not able to Memoize this Recursive Code into Top Down DP

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, memoization

I got this problem on one of my tests. I wrote a Recursive solution for it (I tried it on a few test cases, it seems to be working fine). I am trying to memoize this code, but am not able to do that.

The problem statement goes like this,

You are playing Fantasy Cricket on IPL11 App. The game is a bit different from other Fantasy Cricket Apps.
Here you are given two lists of players. Both lists contain `n` players each.
The list is denoted based on the value they provide.

You need to select exactly `n` players out of these `2*n` players.

The selection needs to be done based on the following rules.

- You can select either from the end of `list1` or end of `list2`
- Once you select a player, he is removed from that list.
- To get access to better players, you also have an option to discard a player and remove them
  from the end of the list. You can do the discard operation at most k times.

Naturally, you would want to get the maximum value possible in your team. Find the maximum value that you can get after selecting `n` players from the 2 lists based on the above rules.

Example

```
n: 6
list1: [10, 13, 31, 12, 12, 18]
list2: [34, 12, 3, 23, 11, 13]
k: 2
```

```
O/P: 112
```

```
Explanation:

* Select 18 (list1)
* Select 13 (list2)
* Skip 11 (list2)
* Select 23 (list2)
* Select 12 (list1)
* Skip 3 (list2)
* Select 12 (list2)
* Select 34 (list2)
```

My Recursive Solution,

```
public static int helper(int[] list1, int[] list2, int n1, int n2, int k, int count) {
        if(count == n) return 0;
        int chooseFromList1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int chooseFromList2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        if(n1 > 0) {
            chooseFromList1 = list1[n1-1]+helper(list1, list2, n1-1, n2, k, count+1);
        }
        if(n2 > 0) {
            chooseFromList2 = list2[n2-1]+helper(list1, list2, n1, n2-1, k, count+1);
        }
        int temp = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        if(k > 0) {
            int skipList1 = helper(list1, list2, n1-1, n2, k-1, count);
            int skipList2 = helper(list1, list2, n1, n2-1, k-1, count);
            temp = Math.max(skipList1, skipList2);
        }
        return Math.max(Math.max(chooseFromList1, chooseFromList2), temp);
    }
```

What I did is, I took 4 choices in this recursive code,

- Take last element from `list1` if n1 > 0
- Take last element from `list2` if n2 > 0
- Skip last element from `list1` if k > 0
- Skip last element from `list2` if k > 0

I want to convert it to Top Down DP, but not able to write the code for it.

Comment: Any constraints on `n`?

Comment: I am sorry, but I forgot the constraints

Answer (score 1):

Naively, the key to memoize for a given pair of lists is going to be `[n1, n2, k, count]`.  This will produce working code. And since data structures are passed by reference, you can simply make the cache be an argument to your `helper` function.

But how much memory will it take?  Well, given starting conditions, there will be `O(n)` choices for `n1`, `O(n)` choices for `n2` and `O(k)` choices for the temporary `k` passed in.  All of which is kept in memory, for `O(k n^2)` memory.  And a similar number of steps.

If I was setting this up for a competition, I would choose `n` and `k` sufficiently large that this naive approach will run out of memory and/or take too long to run.  For example make them both 1000, so you use gigabytes of memory on the cache, and have to call the function a billion times.

How then could you make this more efficient?  Well, the order of operations doesn't matter much.  From each list you'll choose some number of items, and make some number of discards.  So have your helper function just analyze one list.  Now for each list you need `O(k n)` pieces of data which takes `O(k n)` work to generate.

A clever bottom up approach can actually make this run in `O(n)` memory and `O(n log(n))` time.  But that requires serious cleverness and multiple heaps.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the n log(n) solution for the problem, which is a very fun extension. It does seem like using binary search trees may be cleaner than using heaps, though.

Comment: @kcsquared I figured out the heaps solution. I didn't figure out the binary search tree one. But "pick all from one list the best way possible, walk one element at a time to the other" feels pretty clean to me.